# How to define a protocol with an array of a protocol with an associated type

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a protocol (AppStore) which requires the conformer to implement an array of items (subscriptions) that conform to a protocol (Subscriber) that has an associated type.

**goal**
You can think of AppStore like an NSNotificationCenter. I want to add subscribers (like addObserver...). When something happens call handleNewState on the subscribers (like handleNotification:) and pass in an AppState conformer that actually has some variables set on it. The stock AppState doesn't have any properties available.

```
public protocol AppStore {
    //trying to have an array of subscriptions in the protocol
    //but a concrete Subscriber type needs to be specified, I thought a generic Subscriber would be more flexible here?
    var subscriptions:[Subscription<>]{get set}// Reference to generic type 'Subscription' requires arguments in <...>

    associatedtype AppStateType:AppState
    var appState:AppStateType { get set }
}
extension AppStore {
    //so that AppStore can implement this function
    public mutating func subscribe<T:protocol<Subscriber, AnyObject>>(aSubscriber:T){
        subscriptions.append(Subscription(sub:aSubscriber))
    }
}

public protocol Subscriber {
    associatedtype AppStateType
    func handleNewState(newState:AppStateType)
}

public struct Subscription <T:protocol<Subscriber, AnyObject>> {
    private weak var subscriber:T? = nil
    init(sub:T){
        self.subscriber = sub
    }
}
public protocol AppState { }
```

How am I supposed to define `var subscriptions:[Subscription<>]?` Or should I be doing this a different way

I would use it like this

```
public struct OSXAppState:AppState {
     var someStateProp:Int = 0
}
extension NSView : Subscriber { 
    public func handleNewState(newState:OSXAppState){
         if newState == 1 { //do this }
         else { //do that }
    } 
}
public struct OSXAppStore : AppStore {
    public typealias GenericSubscriber = NSView//???: something more generic "anything that implements Subscriber"
    public var subscriptions: [Subscription<GenericSubscriber>] = []
    public var appState: AppState = OSXAppState()
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your goal in more detail? What problem are you trying to solve with this code? This may not be the most direct way toward that goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you were adhering to `AnyObject` in order to be able to use `weak`. This can be done more simply by making the protocol class-only. I changed the protocol composition

`protocol<Subscriber, AnyObject>`

to

`protocol Subscriber: class`

I also added

`associatedtype GenericSubscriber: SubscriberType`

to allow the generic

`Subscription<T: SubscriberType>`

to be used in the array.

```
public protocol Subscriber: class {
  associatedtype AppStateType:AppState
  func handleNewState(newState:AppStateType)
}

public struct Subscription<T:Subscriber> {
  private weak var subscriber:T?
  init(sub:T){
    self.subscriber = sub
  }
}

public protocol AppState { }

public protocol AppStore {
  // Allows Subscription<T:Subscriber> to be used as an array element
  associatedtype GenericSubscriber:Subscriber

  var subscriptions:[Subscription<GenericSubscriber>]{get set}
  var appState:AppState { get set }
}

extension AppStore {
  // The concrete type of GenericSubscriber is inferred from this context
  public mutating func subscribe(aSubscriber: GenericSubscriber){
    subscriptions.append(Subscription<GenericSubscriber>(sub:aSubscriber))
  }
}

public struct OSXAppState:AppState {
  var someStateProp:Int
}
extension NSView : Subscriber {
  public func handleNewState(newState:OSXAppState){
  }
}
```

Comment: The `associatedtype AppStateType` is the key piece here. I want to create an AppState conformer that uses it's own AppState type. `public struct OSXAppState:AppState { }`.  Without AppStateType how do I do this `extension NSView : Subscriber { public func handleNewState(newState:  OSXAppState ){ } }`  (newState:  **OSXAppState** )

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect how you are using the code.

Comment: Thank you! So, how would I implement a struct that conforms to AppStore? The use I have only allows NSView but I would to allow anything that conforms to Subscriber. I updated my use case code to include OSXAppStore.