# How can I extend a protocol with an associated type in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift3, swift-protocols

I'm new to Swift and have been messing around with some code.  I've defined a Layout class similar to the WWDC talk on protocol oriented programming.  It looks like this:

```
protocol Layout {

    associatedtype Content: AnyObject

    var contents: [Content] { get }

    func layout()
}
```

Basically, I'd like a protocol layout which knows how to lay out some type of content (NSViews, UIViews, etc).

I'd like to extend this protocol like so:

```
protocol StackableLayout : Layout {
    var children: [Layout] { get set }
}
```

Where a StackableLayout is a layout that can handle an array of things of type layout.  However this doesn't compile because of the associated type on Layout.

This compiles:

```
protocol StackableLayout : Layout {
    associatedtype Child: Layout
    var children: [Child] { get set }
}
```

But enforces that everything I'm stacking be of the same type:

```
struct YStackLayout<Child: Layout> : StackableLayout {

    var children: [Child]
```

So I can't have a YStackLayout of arbitrary Layout items.  How can I accomplish this?

I came across these posts which look similar but I can't figure out how to apply them:
[How to define a protocol with an array of a protocol with an associated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892534/how-to-define-a-protocol-with-an-array-of-a-protocol-with-an-associated-type)
[How do I add different types conforming to a protocol with an associated type to a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762045/how-do-i-add-different-types-conforming-to-a-protocol-with-an-associated-type-to)

**EDIT:** It seems that type-erasure is what I need here.  A linked example:

```
struct AnyAnimal<Food>: Animal {
    private let _feed: (Food) -> Void
    init<Base: Animal where Food == Base.Food>(_ base: Base) {
        _feed = base.feed
    }
    func feed(food: Food) { _feed(food) }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, otherwise `yStackLayout.children[0].contents` and `yStackLayout.children[1].contents` will have different types determined at runtime

Comment: You'd need [type erasures](http://robnapier.net/erasure) for this.

Comment: This looks like what I need.  Question though...why is this the way they do it? struct AnyAnimal<Food>: Animal {
    private let _feed: (Food) -> Void
    init<Base: Animal where Food == Base.Food>(_ base: Base) {
        _feed = base.feed
    }
    func feed(food: Food) { _feed(food) }
}  Why not just grab base and call the function on it in its feed method?